# Roles are not correct while getting it in hook_user

Tags: hooks

I have added a new role called pre-auth i.e. if a user is registered and has not clicked the confirmation link(using LoginToboggan module) from the mail and the other is authenticated role its the normal authenticated role. I have a hook_user to check the role but it gives me as "authenticated user " always but in `admin/user/user/` it shows the role as  "pre-auth"

```
function mynewmod_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL){
  switch ($op){
  case 'insert':
  case 'after_update':
    $user_details = user_load($account->uid);
    drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($user_details->roles, true) .'</pre>');
}
```

Can any one tell me how can I get the exact role.

Comment: Check for $account variable for roles. I think it should work what are you expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The variable $account already has the loaded user object. Calling $account->roles will give you an array of roles.